# Can't loop json object (facebook opengraph api)

Tags: php, json, facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

I recently made a little script that shows all posts from a Facebook page on a website with custom styles, now I want to extend that script by also showing events. So I asked a question on stackoverflow and came to this line:

```
$json_object = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/165327986836920?fields=events%7Bname%2Cdescription%7D%2Cfeed&access_token=1234");
```

This gives me the following result in the opengraph api tester:

```
{
  "events": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "InfraTech 2019",
        "id": "255151358248763"
      },
      {
        "name": "26e editie Nacht van Oranje",
        "description": "Traditioneel op de avond voor Koningsdag vindt in Ahoy het grootste Hollandse Muziekfeest plaats: de Nacht van Oranje. Dat betekent feest en meezingen met de grootste hits van vaderlandse top-artiesten, de medleyblokken en afsluiter Lee Towers. Alle songteksten verschijnen op lichtkranten boven het podium, dus trek je oranjepak aan en doe mee. 

Voor dit evenement geldt een minimumleeftijd van 18 jaar. Er kan bij het evenement worden gevraagd om legitimatie in geval van twijfel over leeftijd.",
        "id": "1846453685675848"
      },
      {
        "name": "Premier League Darts in Rotterdam Ahoy",
        "description": "De beste darters ter wereld komen terug naar Rotterdam! De PDC heeft bekend gemaakt dat de twaalfde speelronde van de Premier League op 19 april plaats zal vinden in Rotterdam Ahoy! Het dartsnajaar moet nog beginnen, maar we kijken nu al uit naar 19 april.",
        "id": "1620470334638329"
      },
      {
        "name": "The Kelly Familiy - We got love - Live 2018",
        "description": "Een nieuwe Europese tournee brengt The Kelly Family, na bijna 20 jaar afwezigheid, naar Rotterdam Ahoy",
        "id": "1626667994025061"
      },
      {
        "name": "Planet Earth II - Live In Concert",
        "description": "Op 17 maart 2018 geniet je in Rotterdam Ahoy van Planet Earth II – Live In Concert! De indrukwekkende en immens populaire wildlife serie van de BBC wordt dan in 4K-ultra HD-formaat vertoond. De prachtige natuurbeelden worden begeleid door een score van componist en Academy Award-winnaar Hans Zimmer. De kaartverkoop start aanstaande vrijdag 19 mei om 10:00 uur via http://PlanetEarthLive.nl.",
        "id": "121210678451554"
      },
      {
        "name": "Wooning Zesdaagse van Rotterdam 2018",
        "description": "Elk jaar komt in Rotterdam Ahoy een keur van de beste baanrenners ter wereld samen. Zes dagen felle wielerstrijd in de koppelkoers, achter de derny en op de sprint. Absolute topsport. Gezellige ambiance. En een uitgebreid en afwisselend programma! Met o.a. wereldkampioenen koppelkoers Morgan Kneisky en Benjamin Thomas.",
        "id": "124449708142572"
      },
      {
        "name": "Johan Derksen en de Pioniers van de Nederpop",
        "description": "Na twee succesvolle theaterseizoenen zal Johan Derksen met zijn voorstelling 'Johan Derksen en de Pioniers van de Nederpop’ De Finale spelen op donderdag 28 december 2017 in Ahoy.

Samen met de Haagse band 'The Clarks’ en de zangers van 'The Golden Earrings’, 'The Shoes’, 'Johnny Kendall and the Heralds’, 'Alquin’ en 'The Motions’ en gitarist Erwin Java (o.a. 'Cuby and the Blizzards’) zoekt Johan Derksen de fans nog één laatste keer op met zijn voorstelling: 'Johan Derksen en de Pioniers van de Nederpop’. De afgelopen twee theaterseizoenen waren voor Johan en zijn Pioniers een waar genot, de voorstelling werd enthousiast ontvangen door zowel pers als publiek. In het najaar zal 'Johan Derksen en de Pioniers van de Nederpop’ eerst nog te zien zijn in de Nederlandse theaters, waarna Derksen de theatertour in december groots zal afsluiten in Ahoy.

Terug naar de jaren '60
'Johan Derksen en de Pioniers van de Nederpop’ is voor het publiek een feest der herkenning. \"Deze artiesten hebben de basis gelegd voor de hedendaagse muziekscene”, vertelt Derksen. \"Bezoekers zien populaire artiesten van veertig, vijftig jaar geleden optreden. Dat zorgt voor een emotionele avond. De muziek doet terugdenken aan eerste liefdes, bijzondere dansavonden en het gevoel van een eeuwige jeugd.”

Voor en na de show wordt een expositie opgesteld door Museum RockArt. De expositie bestaat uit bijzondere affiches, gitaren, cd’s, lp’s en boeken uit de Nederlandse popgeschiedenis vanaf de jaren 50 tot heden.",
        "id": "1245336535586002"
      },
      {
        "name": "Disney On Ice - Betoverende Werelden",
        "description": "Stap in de betoverende wereld van Disney magie, live op het ijs! Bereid je voor op non-stop plezier met vier van je favoriete Disney-verhalen met Disney/Pixar’s Cars, De Kleine Zeemeermin, Toy Story en Disney’s Frozen.  Beleef de magie met de hele familie!

15 t/m 30 december - Rotterdam, Utrecht en Amsterdam

Nederlandse gesproken | Tickets vanaf € 18,=",
        "id": "1397335660320373"
      },
      {
        "name": "Waylon Live in Concert 2017",
        "description": "Met twee uitverkochte concerten op 24 en 25 november hebben Waylon en Radio Veronica besloten om deze succesvolle samenwerking voort te zetten. Op 1 en 2 december 2017 zal Waylon opnieuw het podium in Rotterdam Ahoy betreden. In Waylon Live in Concert, Radio Veronica Top 1000 Allertijden, zingt de zanger live met zijn eigen band de grootste hits uit de lijst der lijsten. De kaartverkoop start vrijdag 25 november om 09.00 uur via Ticketpoint.",
        "id": "1207659562650103"
      },
      {
        "name": "I Love Urban - Rotterdam Ahoy",
        "description": "JANDINO presenteert I LOVE URBAN

Rotterdam Ahoy opent op 25 november haar deuren voor I LOVE URBAN – Nature of the Beast gepresenteerd door niemand minder dan JANDINO! I LOVE URBAN is het grootste Urban Indoor Festival van Nederland met spectaculaire dansshows, entertainment en komedie. Nog nooit eerder in Nederland vertoond!!!

10.000 partypeople die komen voor The Biggest Urban Indoor Festival van Nederland naar ROTTERDAM!

Tickets: www.iloveurban.com 

Clever Fox Tickets €20,- (SOLD OUT)
Wise Owl Tickets €27,50
Lazy Panda Tickets €35,-
Cheetah Sprint Tickets €40,-

#NatureOfTheBeast

I LOVE URBAN X Indoor Festival 
Zaterdag 25 November
Rotterdam Ahoy
Min. leeftijd: 18",
        "id": "388381531520240"
      },
      {
        "name": "Night of the Proms",
        "description": "Het grote feest van klassiek en pop! Het orkest Antwerp Philharmonic Orchestra - onder leiding van de nieuwe dirigente Alexandra Arrieche - brengt muziek uit de laatste drie eeuwen. En daarnaast brengen popsterren hun grootste hits ten gehore, onder leiding van het huisorkest.",
        "id": "138812583388266"
      },
      {
        "name": "Europort 2017",
        "description": "Europort, organised in the world port city of Rotterdam, is the international maritime meeting place for innovative technology and complex shipbuilding. Europort has a strong focus on special purpose ships including offshore vessels, dredging vessels, construction vessels, naval vessels, workboats, inland vessels, fishery vessels and super yachts. With almost 30,000 professional visitors and 1100 exhibiting companies Europort belongs to the world’s leading maritime meeting places.",
        "id": "120459948495666"
      },
      {
        "name": "Spaanse Rijschool uit Wenen in Rotterdam Ahoy",
        "description": "Op 27, 28 en 29 oktober komen de Lipizzaners van de Spaanse Rijschool opnieuw naar Rotterdam! De Piaffe, de Levade, de Courbette en de Capriole. Het zijn stuk voor stuk de meesterstukken die de witte hengsten uit Wenen met hun berijders tot in de perfectie beheersen. Met als absolute kroonjuweel van de Klassieke Rijkunst: ‘Werk aan de Lange Teugel’. Het voorprogramma zal in een later stadium bekend gemaakt worden. 

Meer informatie over tickets en VIP-arrangementen vindt u op http://www.spaanserijschool.nl/tickets.",
        "id": "1846969912210076"
      },
      {
        "name": "The Tribute Tour 2017- Ustad Rahat Fateh Ali Khan Live Rotterdam",
        "description": "Living legend Ustad Rahat Fateh Ali Khan returns to Ahoy, Rotterdam for one night only in what promises to be a stellar performance in the The Tribute Tour 2017.

2017 marks the 20th year since the death of Ustad Nusrat Fateh Ali Khan. Regarded as one of the greatest singer in the genre of Qawali, Ustad Nusrat Fateh Ali Khan brought qawali to the international stage. He collaborated with and influenced numerous musicians. His nephew, Rahat Fateh Ali Khan, is proof that his legacy continues. 

Rahat Fateh Ali Khan has captured the hearts of millions worldwide and continues to mesmerize audiences with his melodious voice and Sufi music. He has had award winning hits for films such as Sultan, Dabangg, My name is Khan, Son of Sardar and many more. 

Rahat lovers can look forward to a special 4 hour electrifying performance where he will rock the stage with his greatest Bollywood hits and a very special, one time only, tribute to his mentor. A show that cannot be missed.",
        "id": "1711980435766190"
      },
      {
        "name": "La La Land in Concert: A Live-To-Film Celebration at Ahoy",
        "description": "Dit najaar beleef je de met 6 Oscars bekroonde film La La Land op een unieke manier: op groot scherm met de filmmuziek live gespeeld door een 80-koppig symfonisch orkest. “Met de originele stemopnames van Emma Stone, Ryan Gosling en John Legend, live begeleid door de muzikanten, kunnen we een unieke concertervaring bieden waar filmbeelden, opnames en uitmuntende livemuziek elkaar ontmoeten”, vertelt La La Land in Concert producent Richard Kraft.",
        "id": "1918915121721907"
      },
      {
        "name": "UB40 Back at Ahoy - Sold Out",
        "description": "Dat UB40 een speciale band met Nederland in het algemeen en Rotterdam in het bijzonder heeft, blijkt uit het feit dat geen enkele internationale artiest vaker in Ahoy stond dan de Britse reggaegroep. UB40 komt op 20 oktober 2017 namelijk voor de negenentwintigste maal naar het Rotterdamse Ahoy, een record voor een internationale act in de Rotterdamse arena. 

UB40's Robin Campbell: \"We are delighted to be returning for our 29th visit to the AHOY. It’s one of our favourite venues in the world and we look forward to seeing everyone there!” 

De huidige bezetting bestaat uit 'founding members’ Jimmy Brown (drums), Robin Campbell (co-lead vocals/gitaar), Earl Falconer (bas/zang), Norman Hassan (percussie/zang) en Brian Travers (sax/toetsen), plus Duncan Campbell (lead vocals, sinds hij 8 jaar geleden het stokje overnam van zijn broer), Martin Meredith (sax/keys), Lawrence Parry (trompet) en Tony Mullings (toetsen).

Voor de liefhebbers van onvervalste pop-reggae hits en steengoede livemuziek is 'UB40 Back at Ahoy' een niet te missen muzikale feestavond.",
        "id": "234205277001146"
      },
      {
        "name": "André Hazes - Live in Ahoy",
        "description": "Haal net als André Hazes alles uit het leven en kom 14 oktober feesten in Ahoy!

André Hazes wordt door Nederland omarmt. Wanneer 'Leef' klinkt wordt het glas geheven en de daad bij het woord gevoegd. André weet van elke gelegenheid een feest te maken. Hij is een jonge man met (h)eerlijke emotie en het hart op de tong.

Na 5 uitverkochte concerten van de jubileumeditie van Holland Zingt Hazes houdt Nederland van Hazes als nooit tevoren. Hoogste tijd dus om een nieuw Hazes avontuur aan te kondigen: André Hazes – Live in Ahoy.

 Nederlands nieuwste volksheld geeft op 14 oktober 2017 een groots opgezet concert in Ahoy. Het publiek kan zich onder meer verheugen op alle hits van het album 'Leef' én op de live première van de nummers van zijn nieuwe album dat heel binnenkort uitkomt.

Leef mee met André Hazes. Zijn grootste avontuur tot nu toe – Live in ahoy! Haal net als André Hazes alles uit het leven en kom 14 oktober feesten in Ahoy!",
        "id": "1935214196697929"
      },
      {
        "name": "André Hazes - Live in Ahoy",
        "description": "Hazes in Ahoy doorslaand succes!

Wegens groot succes extra concert op 13 oktober!

Een paar weken geleden kondigde Nederlands nieuwste volksheld het eerste concert van Andre Hazes in Ahoy aan. Het concert was in no time uitverkocht en fans vroegen massaal om een extra concert. Om die reden geeft de zanger een extra concert op 13 oktober. Verzeker jezelf dus snel van kaarten want op=op.

 André Hazes wordt door Nederland omarmd. Wanneer 'Leef' klinkt wordt het glas geheven en de daad bij het woord gevoegd. André weet van elke gelegenheid een feest te maken. Hij is een jonge man met (h)eerlijke emotie en het hart op de tong. Na 5 uitverkochte concerten van de jubileumeditie van Holland Zingt Hazes houdt Nederland van Hazes als nooit tevoren. Hoogste tijd dus om een nieuw Hazes avontuur aan te kondigen: André Hazes – Live in Ahoy.

Nederlands nieuwste volksheld geeft op 13 en 14 oktober 2017 een groots opgezet concert in Ahoy. Het publiek kan zich onder meer verheugen op alle hits van het album 'Leef' én op de live première van de nummers van zijn nieuwe album dat heel binnenkort uitkomt.

 Haal net als André Hazes alles uit het leven en kom feesten in Ahoy!",
        "id": "425978574436026"
      },
      {
        "name": "100% Tuning 2017",
        "description": "Een unieke combinatie van een grote, internationale selectie van showcars, adembenemende driftshows, de nieuwste hoogstandjes op het gebied van design, performance, car audio en volop entertainment vormden de basis voor 100% Tuning in Rotterdam Ahoy! De 14e editie vindt plaats op 30 september en 1 oktober 2017.",
        "id": "371115026585953"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ennio Morricone in Rotterdam - The 60 Years of Music Tour",
        "description": "Ennio Morricone gaat zijn filmmuziek live ten gehore brengen in Rotterdam Ahoy op 19 september 2017. Het concert is een onderdeel van zijn ’60 Years Of Music Tour’ waarbij ook de Portugese fadolegende Dulce Pontes Oficial zal optreden als speciale gastzangeres. De concertreeks kende wereldwijd al uitvoeringen in uitverkochte concertzalen en kreeg staande ovaties en lovende recensies in de media. De show met nieuw programma in Ahoy zal de enige show zijn van de maestro in de Benelux.",
        "id": "1875983579284810"
      },
      {
        "created_time": "2017-09-02T09:32:18+0000",
        "message": "Gisteren vonden de Weigh-Ins plaats, vandaag gaan Struve en Volkov het gevecht aan in Ahoy!  #UFCRotterdam",
        "story": "Rotterdam Ahoy shared UFC's video.",
        "id": "165327986836920_1444536738916032"
      },
      {
        "created_time": "2017-09-02T06:29:19+0000",
        "story": "Rotterdam Ahoy shared UFC's event.",
        "id": "165327986836920_1444455895590783"
      },
      {
        "created_time": "2017-09-01T07:00:00+0000",
        "message": "Het wachten is voorbij! Het is tijd om de magie en de muziek van de tijdloze werelden van Cars, de Kleine Zeemeermin, Toy Story en Frozen te ontdekken. Disney On Ice presenteert Betoverende Werelden schaatst van 15 t/m 17 december in Rotterdam Ahoy. Daarna kun je deze prachtige ijsshow nog bewonderen in Utrecht en Amsterdam. Tickets zijn nu te koop via www.disneyonice.nl!",
        "id": "165327986836920_1442936242409415"
      },
      {
        "created_time": "2017-08-30T15:10:29+0000",
        "story": "Rotterdam Ahoy shared Bollywood Concerts's event.",
        "id": "165327986836920_1442206625815710"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5TXhOalV6TWpjNU9EWTRNelk1TWpBNk1UZAzFPVEl4T1RnNU5ERXdNRGN6T1RNNU1BOE1ZAWEJwWDNOMGIzSjVYMmxrRHlBeE5qVXpNamM1T0RZANE16WTVNakJmTVRRMU1qY3pOekkyTVRReU9UTXhNdzhFZAEdsdFpRWlp0NlFYQVE9PQZDZD",
        "after": "Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5TXhOalV6TWpjNU9EWTRNelk1TWpBNk16SXpNREU1TURnME1URXlOVFU0TlRVeE5BOE1ZAWEJwWDNOMGIzSjVYMmxrRHlBeE5qVXpNamM1T0RZANE16WTVNakJmTVRRME1qSXdOall5TlRneE5UY3hNQThFZAEdsdFpRWlpwdFZAsQVE9PQZDZD"
      },
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/165327986836920/feed?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAI6kSG9KINOKhebbUvA17YPwSDg9bhPOZAsQDSXArDdxiXqPEWK2VIvTvVBleSilc63FC4gCJKRGQk5Xqf6aqvZCT2uOwDDZBF3ZBWLiW0dW28RPTueZCARdP5oS8tAOiMHjNPWvWmyNnantNoiX23HkkMnN74d3POs3Ryx5HN7udZCXVRjLoZD&pretty=0&limit=25&after=Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5TXhOalV6TWpjNU9EWTRNelk1TWpBNk16SXpNREU1TURnME1URXlOVFU0TlRVeE5BOE1ZAWEJwWDNOMGIzSjVYMmxrRHlBeE5qVXpNamM1T0RZANE16WTVNakJmTVRRME1qSXdOall5TlRneE5UY3hNQThFZAEdsdFpRWlpwdFZAsQVE9PQZDZD"
    }
  },
  "id": "165327986836920"
}
```

(I removed most of the object because my post would be too long).

So that is giving me the warning:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/studione/public_html/_extern/website/events.php on line 75
```

While with the following code, everything works fine (no events, only the feed):

```
$json_object = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/165327986836920/posts?fields=name%2Cfull_picture%2Cmessage%2Cstory%2Cpermalink_url%2Cupdated_time%2Cfrom&access_token=1234");
```

My loop always stays the same, only the way I retrieve the object changes.

Here is my entire code (currently it only echoes data from the feed object):

```
<?
$json_object = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/165327986836920/posts?fields=name%2Cfull_picture%2Cmessage%2Cstory%2Cpermalink_url%2Cupdated_time%2Cfrom&access_token=1234");


$feedarray = json_decode($json_object);

$f = 0;

foreach ( $feedarray->data as $key => $feed_data )
{

    if($feed_data->full_picture != ''){
        $fbimage = $feed_data->full_picture;
    }else{
        $fbimage = 'images/backgroundheader.jpg';
    }

    $shortstrfb = substr($feed_data->message, 0, 170) . '...';
    if($feed_data->message != ''){
        $f++;
    }

    if($f > 10){
        break;
    }

    if($feed_data->message != '' && $feed_data->from->name == 'Rotterdam Ahoy'){
        $facebookfeed .= '
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 blog-isotope-item">
                    <div class="itemContainer zn_columns zn_columns3">
                        <div class="itemThumbnail">
                            <a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'" target="_blank">
                                <img width="760" height="508" src="'.$fbimage.'" class="wp-post-image" alt="'.$feed_data->name.'">
                            </a>

                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="overlay__inner">
                                    <a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'" target="_blank" class="readMore" title="" data-readmore="Bekijk op Facebook"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="itemHeader">
                            <h3 class="itemTitle">
                                <a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'" target="_blank">'.$feed_data->name.'</a>
                            </h3>

                            <div class="post_details">
                                <span class="catItemDateCreated"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> '.date("d-m-Y",strtotime($feed_data->updated_time)).'</span>
                                <span class="catItemAuthor">by <a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'" title="'.$feed_data->name.'" rel="author">'.$feed_data->name.'</a></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="itemBody">
                            <div class="itemIntroText">
                                '.$shortstrfb.'
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
    }
}
echo $facebookfeed;
?>
```

What is triggering the warning?

Comment: _“What is triggering the warning?”_ - the fact that you are trying to access a `data` property on the top level (`$feedarray->data`), despite the fact that there isn’t one. What key does the data structure you have shown start with on the top-most level …?

Comment: Okay I didn't notice that changed, but when I change data into events, I get nothing, no warning but also no data. Is it possible to loop both data and events in one loop?

Comment: You get no warnings, because you don’t have your PHP error reporting configured correctly for developing purposes - so do that first of all.

Comment: And of course just switching out `data` for `events` won’t do - you need to access `events` first, and then the `data` located below that. Since this property occurs only once, `$feedarray->events->data` should do at this point.

Comment: @CBroe I turned on all errors and it shows me this notice looped for `$message` and `$fullpicture` echoed variable: `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$full_picture in /home/studione/public_html/_extern/website/events.php on line 80` with `$feedarray->events->data` already added.

Comment: Alright the notices are because I don't get them with the filegetcontents so I changed that and tested it in the graph api tester. But now I get `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/studione/public_html/_extern/website/events.php on line 95` which is `if($feed_data->from->name == 'Rotterdam Ahoy'){` and in the tester it shows like this: `"feed": {
    "data": [
      {
        "from": {
          "name": "Rotterdam Ahoy",
          "id": "165327986836920"
        },
        "id": "165327986836920_1452737261429313"
      },`

Comment: Are you looping over the feed part of the data here, or the events part? The events don’t have a `from` field.

Comment: The events part, I thought all info was inside one key (if that is the correct word for it) but I see theyre in `feed` and `events` while I need values from both keys inside my loop. But I think that is enough information for another question. @CBroe